# How to Create Dependable Parameter in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I want to create a report which has two parameters. 
1. @Booking
2. @Program

Every booking has many programs. I want that when I select "@Booking" then "@Program" is populated automatically and get program record according to booking.

Comment: any relation between booking and program tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for **Cascading Parameters**.

This when you have parameters populated by Datasets, and the query for the second Dataset references the first parameter.

For a very simple example, the first parameter's Dataset will be populated by:

```
select * from Booking
```

And the second by:

```
select * from Program
where Booking = @Booking
```

Where `@Booking` is the name of the first parameter.

See the official documentation [Add Cascading Parameters to a Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255197.aspx) for much more detail.